# How do I resolve the SSAS Tabular error stating changes could not be committed to the vertipaq engine?

Tags: ssas-tabular

I'm trying to save my credentials in Visual Studio 2019 so that I can process my SSAS Tabular model. I'm getting an error message stating that changes could not be committed to the vertipaq engine. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were unsaved changes to the model. The solution is to save the model prior to updating credentials.